# How to add a legend after arrange several plots using `ggarrange` from the ggpubr package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have got to create this arrange of different plots using `ggarrange`:

```
arrange <- ggarrange(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5, ncol=3,nrow = 2,common.legend = F, align = c("hv"))
arrange
```

[image]

I would like to add a common legend, so I did this:

```
arrange <- ggarrange(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5, ncol=3,nrow = 2,common.legend = T, align = c("hv"),legend="top")
arrange
```

[image]

However, I would like the legend was in the right lower part of the graph, in the "blank" space.

Do you know how could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it exist simpler and easier solution but just a quick way around is to create an empty plot with only the legend to be display and use to fill the last emplacement in `ggarrange`.

Here using `iris` dataset, you can first generate the five plot by specifying `legend.position = "none"` in `theme` to remove the legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Then, you draw an empty plot with only the legend to be display in the middle of the plot area. You can increase the size of all elements of the ggplot in order to make it visible on the final figure panel:

```r
p3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species))+
  geom_point()+
  lims(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,0))+
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5,0.5),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.text = element_text(size =  12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=8)))
```

Now, you can use `ggarrange` and specify p3 to be your last plot:

```r
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(p2,p2,p2,p2,p2, p3)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Yes!! It answers perfectly!! Just in case is useful to someone else, in the empty plot I added the line `scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))` because in my case, my X variable is categorical with 4 levels. Lastly, when arranging the plots, I also added `align = c("hv")` to `ggarrange()` since in my case, each plot has a different size originally and with this, they are aligned perfectly. But yes, you resolved my main question!!! Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome ;) If you feel satisfied by this answer, feel free to accept it and/or upvote it.